# How can i get select option by id using php

Tags: php

I want to access option of dropdowns by id  using php like i have done in javascript .I want to do this work in php also.Is there any way to do this.Please guide.My JS code is.

```
var opt = amove.options[amove.selectedIndex];

   if(opt.id =="Exchange"){          
      document.getElementById('barcode2lb').style.display='block';

      document.getElementById('barcode2txt').style.display='block';
}
else{

     document.getElementById('barcode2lb').style.display='none';

     document.getElementById('barcode2txt').style.display='none';
}
```

Comment: What do you mean? If you are using [DOMDocument](http://php.net/domdocument) to parse HTML in PHP, the method name is exactly the same: [DOMDocument::getElementById()](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementbyid.php).

Answer (score 0):

if you using raw php then

```
<select name="">
  <option value=""> select a option </option>
<?php
  $sql = 'SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id ASC';
  $result_select = mysql_query($sql);
  $rows = array();
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_select)){
    if($row['which column you want to compare'] == value){
      echo "<option value="".$row['value index']."">".$row['value index']." </option>"
   }
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

For example,

```
<select>
<?php foreach($yourArr as $row):
if(yourConidtion){
  $selected='selected';
}else{
  $selected='';
}?>
<option value="<?= $row->id?>" <?= $selected ?>><?= $row->name ?></option>
<?php endforeach;?>
</select>
```

I think this is what you asked for

Answer (score 0):

`PHP` is a server side language therefore you will need your `JS` to post your id values using [AJAX](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ajax/what_is_ajax.htm). Make an AJAX call from your `JS` code and handle the data in your `PHP` code